# Como Localizar um valor entre colunas

Tags: r

```
x = data.frame(Índice = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                Data = as.Date(c("2019-01-22", "2019-01-21", "2019-01-20", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-17", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-10")),
                Valor = c(20,25,28,42,59,18,72,63,18,42), 
                Busca = c(59,18,0,0,42,28,0,18,0,50))
```

Tenho um data frame `x`, e na coluna de nome `Busca`, aonde o valor for maior que "0", preciso fazer uma busca deste numero na coluna `Valor` e localizar o primeiro valor igual ao procurado seguindo os índices e inseri-lo em uma nova coluna no mesmo índice que está na coluna `Valor`.

Desta forma, por exemplo, o valor "18", seria retornado no índice "6" em uma nova coluna. O valor "42" no índice "10" e assim por diante.
Como Exemplo deixo o mesmo data frame abaixo com a coluna `Encontrado` da forma como a busca deveria retornar.

```
x = data.frame(Índice = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                Data = as.Date(c("2019-01-22", "2019-01-21", "2019-01-20", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-17", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-10")),
                Valor = c(20,25,28,42,59,18,72,63,18,42), 
                Busca = c(59,18,0,0,42,28,0,18,0,50),
                Encontrado = c(0,0,0,0,59,18,0,0,18,42))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode-se usar `%in%` para criar um índice lógico.
Como os novos valores são iguais aos do vetor `Valor`, vou inicializar o vetor `Encontrado` com o vetor `Valor`.
Depois substituo só os onde os valores do vetor `Busca` não estão por zero.

```
x$Encontrado <- x$Valor
i <- !x$Valor %in% x$Busca
x$Encontrado[i] <- 0
x
#   Índice       Data Valor Busca Encontrado
#1       1 2019-01-22    20    59          0
#2       2 2019-01-21    25    18          0
#3       3 2019-01-20    28     0         28
#4       4 2019-01-18    42     0         42
#5       5 2019-01-17    59    42         59
#6       6 2019-01-16    18    28         18
#7       7 2019-01-15    72     0          0
#8       8 2019-01-14    63    18          0
#9       9 2019-01-11    18     0         18
#10     10 2019-01-10    42    50         42
```

Note-se que este código pode ser simplificado. Em vez de criar explicitamente o índice `i`, pode ser

```
x$Encontrado[!x$Valor %in% x$Busca] <- 0
```

Comment: Isso resolveria parte do problema. Mas note que no valor "Encontrado" que deixei Encontrado = c(0,0,0,0,59,18,0,0,18,42), o valor "28" não aparece igual na sua tabela, pois esse valor está em uma data anterior a que foi buscado, então não teria que aparecer. Mesma coisa aconteceria com o "42", que teria que aparecer somente na última posição, pois a data a partir de onde está sendo buscado é mais antiga. Somente tem que ser feita a busca a partir da data encontrada na coluna "Busca", seguindo em datas mais antigas.

Answer (score 0):

Seria isto?

```
x = data.frame(Índice = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
            Data = as.Date(c("2019-01-22", "2019-01-21", "2019-01-20", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-17", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-10")),
            Valor = c(20,25,28,42,59,18,72,63,18,42),
            Busca = c(59,18,0,0,42,28,0,18,0,50))
```

todos os elementos da nova coluna igual a 0

```
x$Encontrado <- 0
```

indices em que `x$Busca > 0`, assumem `x$Valor`

```
x$Encontrado[x$Busca>0] <- x$Valor[x$Busca>0]
x
#   Índice       Data Valor Busca Encontrado
# 1       1 2019-01-22    20    59         20
# 2       2 2019-01-21    25    18         25
# 3       3 2019-01-20    28     0          0
# 4       4 2019-01-18    42     0          0
# 5       5 2019-01-17    59    42         59
# 6       6 2019-01-16    18    28         18
# 7       7 2019-01-15    72     0          0
# 8       8 2019-01-14    63    18         63
# 9       9 2019-01-11    18     0          0
# 10     10 2019-01-10    42    50         42
```

Comment: Não. Note que deixei como ficaria a coluna "Encontrado" após a busca Encontrado = c(0,0,0,0,59,18,0,0,18,42). Somente os valores que aparecem na coluna "Busca" que teriam que aparecer na coluna "Encontrado" e também uma coisa muito importante é que somente apareceriam a partir do índice buscado. Como o exemplo do número "42" que apareceria somente na última linha do data frame, mesmo já tendo aparecido na coluna "Valor" anterior ao que apareceu coluna "Busca". O que importa é a partir do índice da coluna "Busca", o que ficou pra trás não tem valor.